# In parallel, dose testng will not continue to execute until all tests which has got thread finised?

Tags: java, testng

recently, I found a strange thing, seems testng will not continue to run until all tests which has got thread finised.
following is the xml, and parallel="classes":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">



<suite name="Demo" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="1">
        <classes>
            <class name="example.A"/>
            <class name="example.B"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="example.C"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**A.java:**

```
public class A {
    @Test
    public void testA(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--AAAA" + i);
            TimeUtil.wait(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
public class B {
    @Test
    public void testA(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--BBBB---->" + i);
            TimeUtil.wait(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**C.java:**

```
public class C {
    @Test
    public void testA(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "--CCCC---->" + i);
            TimeUtil.wait(1);
        }
    }
}
```

following is the output of command "mvn clean test":

```
-------------------------------------------------------
        T E S T S
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Running TestSuite
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA0
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->0
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA1
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->1
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->2
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA2
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->3
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA3
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->4
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA4
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->5
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA5
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->6
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA6
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->7
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA7
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA8
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->8
        TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA9 // A.java is finished in here, and testng did not continue to run C.java, "wait"  TestNG-test=1-2 to be finished.
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->9
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->10
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->11
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->12
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->13
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->14
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->15
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->16
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->17
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->18
        TestNG-test=1-2--BBBB---->19 //TestNG-test=1-2 finished, then C.java begin to execute
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->0
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->1
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->2
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->3
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->4
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->5
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->6
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->7
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->8
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->9
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->10
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->11
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->12
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->13
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->14
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->15
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->16
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->17
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->18
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->19
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->20
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->21
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->22
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->23
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->24
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->25
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->26
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->27
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->28
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->28
        TestNG-test=2-1--CCCC---->29
        Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 51.967 sec
```

we could see that in the line of

```
TestNG-test=1-1--AAAA9 // A.java is finished at here, but TestNG-test=1-1 did not continue to run C.java, but "wait" TestNG-test=1-2 to be finished..so weired
```

I am wondering that whether is it designed like this or a bug ?
**I hope C.java could be executed immediately once A.java is done**, is it possible?

Comment: It is not clear what is expected behavior from your POV. For me it looks like nothing is wrong and it could not work any other way.

Comment: hi, @Vladislav Varslavans, I hope C.java could be executed immediately once A.java is done, is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried `parallel="tests"`?

Comment: parallel="tests" works fine, and C.java will run immediately when A.java is done, but I just want to know whether is it possible when paralles="classes" ?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is working as designed here.

You have specified `thread-count` as `2` at the suite level. So what this means is that TestNG will now create a thread pool which has only 2 threads in it and so all the parallel executions that are being done at the suite level will now have to share this thread pool of size 2.

In your suite you have basically 3 classes. When you kick off the run, TestNG will schedule all the 3 test classes for execution against the thread pool of size two.

Internally the ExecutorService that TestNG uses, will manage the execution such that at any given point in time only 2 classes are getting executed and based on the scheduling, 1 class stands out and waits for the other threads to run to completion.

So yes, `C.java` (or it could even be `A.java` or `B.java` for that matter) would have to wait until the other two run to completion and a thread becomes free in the thread pool